# Speed up macro copy/offset

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Good afternoon,

I have this macro that copies values from a sheet to different pages on another sheet. For example:

Sheet1.A1 to Sheet2.K2, Sheet1.A2 to Sheet2.AA2, Sheet1.A3 to Sheet2.AQ2

I do this by means of:

```
Sheets("Inlog").Range("A1").Activate
For i = 4 To k + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=10).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = Sheets("CBT").Range("J" & i).Value
Next
```

The code in itself works well, but this is not the only loop since I hope to copy multiple ranges from Sheet1 to Sheet2.

My complete macro does the trick, but it takes around 4 minutes to finish. Even longer for my colleagues with a newer version of Excel.

My VBA skills are very basic, so any pro tips or other ways to speed this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to IIJHFIIs suggestion, you should avoid using `ActiveCell` and use `Range`-Objects instead.

You can save a `Range` in a variable by doing `Dim rng as Range` and offsetting it by using

```
Set rng = rng.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=10)
```

They work exactly the same as your `ActiveCell` (because it is also a `Range`-Object) so you can also set the `.Value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try turning screen updates off:

```
application.screenupdating = False

Sheets("Inlog").Range("A1").Activate
For i = 4 To k + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=10).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = Sheets("CBT").Range("J" & i).Value
Next

application.screenupdating = True
```

Should save a bit of time on this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim off As Long
off = 1
For i = 4 To k + 1
    Sheets("Inlog").Cells(1, off * 10).Value = Sheets("CBT").Cells(i, 10).Value
    off = off + 1
Next
```

This should do the same and it should marginally quicker. 
Also, you could disable automatic calculations and screen updating, by putting this a the beginning of your code:

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
```

And this at the end:

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I was copying a value, then copy the next value to the same position but on the next page to right. I rewrote the code so that instead of going a page to the right it goes a page down:

```
For i = 4 To k
Sheets("Inlog").Range("K" & (2 + 16 * (i - 3))) = Sheets("CBT").Range("K" & i)
Next
```

This turns out to be way quicker.

The screenupdating also helps, thanks!